# Is it possible to add a variable that has not been declared in php?

Tags: php

I want to announce the variable whose name is introduced during execution

```
class db_handler {

function appendCol(){
  // get name col
  // get value
}

}

$colname = $_POST("col");
$db = new db_handler();
$db->appendCols()->$colname = "Value";
```

like this [xbase/dbf](https://github.com/luads/php-xbase#writing-data)

example from this lib :

```
$table = new WritableTable($dbf_file);
$table->openWrite();
$record = $table->appendRecord();
foreach ($fields as $field => $val ) {
    $record->$field = $val;
}
$table->writeRecord();
$table->close();
```

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: Do you want to add it as a class attribute?

Comment: i think most use **Magic Methods** right?

Comment: Yes,  but you must use also reflection.